# sending encrypted data in chunks gets corrputed after first chunk

Tags: c++, python-3.x, encryption

I have C++ client encrypting files and send it to a python server which decrypt it and saves it. the encryption and  decryption works fine but when I send larger files I send it in chunks and it seems that the begging of every chunk fro, the second get corrupted:

for  example here is example file I want to send:
[image: what I want to send]

and here is  how the server gets it:
[image: what the server gets]

for smaller files it works fine (1024 is the size of data I read each time

```
//Encrypt the data and save it to temporary file
std::ofstream tempFile("EncryptedFile", std::ios::binary);  
char buffer[MAX_LEN];
std::cout << "The data inside buffer is:\n";
while (!transferFile.eof()) {
    std::fill_n(buffer, sizeof(buffer), '\0');
    transferFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
    std::streamsize bytesRead = transferFile.gcount();
    std::cout << buffer;
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        string encryptedChunk = aesWrapper.encrypt(buffer, bytesRead);
        tempFile.write(encryptedChunk.c_str(), encryptedChunk.size());
    }
}
transferFile.close();
tempFile.close();

//Step 4: get the file size and send  it
std::ifstream tempFileRead("EncryptedFile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize fileSize = tempFileRead.tellg();
tempFileRead.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
string header = createHeader(std::to_string(SEND_FILE));
header += ("\nPayload size: " + std::to_string(fileSize + fileName.length()) + "\nContent Size: ") + std::to_string(fileSize) + "\nFile Name: " + fileName;
std::string utf8_request(header);
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(utf8_request.c_str(), utf8_request.length()));
while (tempFileRead) {
    tempFileRead.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
    std::streamsize bytesRead = tempFileRead.gcount();
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, bytesRead));
    }
}
tempFileRead.close();
std::remove("EncryptedFile");
```

the python code:

```
  iv = b"\x00" * 16  # just for practical use should not be set to 0
UUID = getUUID(request)
AES_Key = DB.getAESKey(UUID)
fileName = getFileName(request)
ContentSize = int(getContentSize(request))
cipher = AES.new(AES_Key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypted_bytes = b''

while ContentSize > 0:
    data = server.getBinaryData()
    ContentSize -= len(data)
    decrypted_bytes += cipher.decrypt(data)

decrypted_text = unpad(decrypted_bytes, AES.block_size)

with open(fileName, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(decrypted_text)
```

it goes to this python code after he recives the header and nows its a request for file sending. I read the bytes from the the file and send it in loop
the:
data = server.getBinaryData()
is just "return conn.recv(1024)"
so baiscally ready the encrypted data files.
the loops it self seems fine the problem is just the start of each data section from the 2nd loop

edit: after doing some checks I was able the confirm that the corrputed data adds in the first loop when I encrypt it

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  removing  the eof doesnt help. the problem is also the beggining of each chuck dont see how eof is  realted to it

Comment: @DaniDubinskey *removing the eof doesnt help* -- The point of the comment made was to correct your code, regardless if it fixes the problem.  The comment section is for comments, not for answers.

Comment: `std::cout << buffer;` -- This will not work correctly if `buffer` contains embedded nulls.  This should be `std::cout.write(buffer, bytesread);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie anyhow, console is not the best place to output binary data; none-printable characters and special characters are likely to show up. The case might beep every other second.

Comment: And the definition of `aesWrapper.encrypt` is where?